# Why do I keep getting logged out all the time these days?

Tags: support

In the old days, I used to stay logged in to Physics.SE (and other Stack Exchange sites) for many weeks at a time. Only very occasionally would I find myself mysteriously logged out, and have to log back in again. But nowadays it seems to happen at least once a day. Why is this, and can I do anything about it?

Comment: Can you specify your OS, browser, and OpenID provider?

Comment: I have not seen such an effect (Opera web browser on Scientific Linux 6.5).

Comment: I see this on one machine but not on another. I use firefox in both cases. The login system is extremely opaque, and its behavior is difficult to understand.

Comment: I have no issues with either Firefox on Linux or on Windows...

Comment: I'm on OS X using Chrome and logging in with Google

Comment: OK, then: to be clear, you're not being logged out of Google, right? Only Stack Exchange? (e.g. when you see yourself being logged out of SE, if you go to the Google homepage, does it still show your account at the top?) My first hunch is something to do with cookies, but it's a tricky problem to track down the exact cause.

Comment: @DavidZ that's right, I don't get logged out of Google, only Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I have recently started seeing the same behavior with OS X Safari, logged in through stackexchange. I'll visit this SE site, some other SE site, yet another SE, go do some work, walk the dogs, etc. I have to log back in when I wake my machine up from sleep to play around on physics.SE. The $\Delta t$ between visits to one particular part of the SE network that forces a re-login now seems to be much less than 24 hours, at least for me.